# Performance issue with List operations

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
if (itemsListFromDbQuery != null && itemsListFromDbQuery.Any())
{
    tempItemsList.Add(new ItemModel
    {
        FieldOne = itemsListFromDbQuery.FirstOrDefault().FieldOne,
        FieldTwo = itemsListFromDbQuery.FirstOrDefault().FieldTwo ?? 0
    });
}
```

It felt somewhat slow so I added a duration log and saw that each time it executes this code it takes an average of 800 ms.

**UPDATE:** Here is the code to get the `itemsListFromDbQuery`:

```
var itemsListFromDbQuery = getListFromDbQuery();

public IEnumerable<Item> getListFromDbQuery()
{
    return DbContext.Items.Where(...);
}
```

Why does this code execute so slowly?
What can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: Well you're potentially running 3 queries (at least) here.

Comment: For performance-issues allways use a profiler such as DotTrace. It shows you exactly where - if even - you´re losing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `itemsListFromDbQuery` looks like an `IQueryable<T>`, which will be executed deferredly.

So: `itemsListFromDbQuery.Any()` and `itemsListFromDbQuery.FirstOrDefault()` (twice) will execute the query again.

Save the entities in a list, or call `FirstOrDefault()` on beforehand:

```
var queryMaterialized = itemsListFromDbQuery.FirstOrDefault();

if (queryMaterialized != null)
{
    tempItemsList.Add(new ItemModel
    {
        FieldOne = queryMaterialized.FieldOne,
        FieldTwo = queryMaterialized.FieldTwo ?? 0
    });
}
```

`itemsListFromDbQuery` will never be `null` anyway.

Comment: I thought I already saved the query result in a IEnumerable. How do I make sure it really does save it in a list and does not executes the query all over again?

Comment: @Palmi Depends on what do you mean by "saving in an IEnumerable"?

Comment: @Palmi you may want to read [ask] and realise we can't see the rest of your code. I felt my assumption was safe enough to warrant writing an answer, but I can't (and won't) answer any followup questions without you showing more code in your question.

Comment: I added the code. I didn't think it was relevant and Stackoverflow does not allow me do post an endless amount of code so I have to filter to what I think is relevant to the issue.

Comment: @Palmi returning an `IQeryable<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't take away the deferred execution. It still returns a promise and not the materialized query result. You need to call either `.ToList()` once, or `FirstOrDefault()` once.